# VGA to PAL on Intel HD

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, sync, resolution, vga

I got a i5 Laptop computer with integrated Intel HD graphics card.
I want to connect to a large CRT TV which has a PAL composite video input (yellow RCA jack!) and three inputs labeled DVD component input (red, green and blue colored RCA JACKs).

I learned following facts from google:

1. The VGA gives out Analog RGB signal with separate h-sync and v-sync!
2. The scan rate of VGA is almost double that of Pal!

However I found a circuit [here](http://www.epanorama.net/circuits/vga2tv/psergio_circuit.html) and many similar that can convert the RGB and sync signals to composite but however they can't deal with the resolution and sync rate. For that I found a section in Intel HD graphics control panel named as custom resolution.

Here I can set custom scan rate and resolution:

[image]

What settings should I use?

What does the DVD input mean in the back of the TV? can it take RGB signal directly if I lower the resolution and scan rate?